# Flutter- show loading screen till firestore document changes

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a ridesharing app with flutter. So far i am stuck on how to communicate between the rider and driver app.
After rider submits pickup request to firestore db, i want the loading screen to show until a driver accepts the request(possibly by updating firestore db) then move to screen with driver info.

```
if (event is PaymentMadeEvent) {
      yield TaxiBookingLoadingState(
          state:
              PaymentNotInitializedState(booking: null, methodsAvaiable: null));
      TaxiBooking booking = await TaxiBookingStorage.addDetails(TaxiBooking.named(paymentMethod: event.paymentMethod));
      String docID = await TaxiBookingController.submitRequest(
        booking.source.areaDetails,
        booking.destination.areaDetails,
        [booking.source.position.latitude,booking.source.position.longitude],
        [booking.destination.position.latitude,booking.destination.position.longitude],
        booking.estimatedPrice,
        booking.estimatedDuration,
        booking.estimatedDistance
      );

      booking =  await TaxiBookingStorage.addDetails(TaxiBooking.named(dbID: docID));
      await TaxiBookingController.generateToken();
      TaxiDriver taxiDriver = await TaxiBookingController.getTaxiDriver(booking);

      // Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) async* {

      // } ); 

       taxiDriver = await TaxiBookingController.getTaxiDriver(booking);  
         yield TaxiNotConfirmedState(booking: booking, driver: taxiDriver);


    }
```

```
static Future<TaxiDriver> getTaxiDriver(TaxiBooking booking) async {
    TaxiDriver taxis2;
     var driver = await Firestore.instance.collection("rider_pickup_pairing")
    //  .where(DocumentReference,isEqualTo: booking.dbID)
     .where("driver_id",isEqualTo: 'jk')
        .getDocuments()
        .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {

      if (snapshot.documents == []) {

        taxis2 =  null;
      } else {
      snapshot.documents.forEach((f)  => 

      taxis2 = TaxiDriver.named(
        driverPic:
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e3/profilepic.jpg",
        driverName: "John Doe",
        driverRating: 4.5,
        taxiDetails: "Toyota Corolla(ABJ823KU)")
        );
        TaxiBookingStorage.addDetails(TaxiBooking.named(driver: taxis2.driverName));
      }
      return taxis2;
      });

      return driver;

  }
```

Comment: Sounds feasible, the driver app [writes to the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data), while the rider app [queries for a specific value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries). Those links should be enough to get you started. If you get stuck, post back with the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have edited the  post with code that reproduces the problem. So far when event 'PaymentMadeEvent' is triggered, it runs fine if firestore query is true but when false if stops at the loading screen and stays there even after firestore gets updated to return the query as true.

Comment: You're using `.getDocuments()`, which only loads the documents once. To keep watching for your specific value, you'll want to [listen for realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `.onSnapshot()` instead of `.getDocument()` in order to achieve this.

The difference between these two methods is that `getDocument()` will only retrieve the document once while `onSnapshot()` will keep listening to any event on Firestore. This is covered in these documents: [get realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) and [get data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data).

Hope you find this useful.